# How to force kubernetes cluster to use local registry?

Tags: kubernetes

My kubernetes cluster (LAB) is cut off today from the internet.
Apparently because of that none of my pods can startup (no problem with pods in kube-system though):

```
  Normal   Pulling         40m (x4 over 42m)      kubelet  Pulling image "nginx:latest"
  Warning  Failed          40m (x4 over 42m)      kubelet  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed          40m                    kubelet  Failed to pull image "nginx:latest": failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:46391->127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout
  Warning  BackOff         39m (x7 over 41m)      kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container nginx in pod nginx-deployment-5b9455bc67-j9sh9_default(46e9f74f-8d35-467b-b294-b8c469f95fa6)
  Warning  Failed          37m                    kubelet  Failed to pull image "nginx:latest": failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:45430->127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout
  Warning  Failed          7m52s (x3 over 18m)    kubelet  (combined from similar events): Failed to pull image "nginx:latest": failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/latest": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:49261->127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout
  Normal   BackOff         2m58s (x150 over 42m)  kubelet  Back-off pulling image "nginx:latest"
```

This is a surprise to me as I thought that any pod that I start on my cluster will first download it's container(s) image to local registry and then the image will be used from here.
Apparently im wrong.

**Question:**
How can I force kubernetse cluster to download/pull the images to the LOCAL registry?

Moreover, although I am cut off from internet, i a still able to export image from the (local) repository. HOW COME???

```
sudo ctr -n k8s.io image export --local testimage docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:18090843a20ba39719ca4f389d509063ea4fcce9d16c7168f62404b6d630bc3e
```

**[UPDATE/SOLUTION]**
If I get it right, all the images I can see with `sudo ctr -n k8s.io image list` are actually in local registry.

What is preventing pods to startup is that in their manifest it is set: `imagePullPolicy: Always`
This means: every time u are starting up look for latest image in the remote/native registry

For test, I have created new POD setting `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` and specifying image name of the pod/container that worked when the internet connectivity was here.
This created pod successfully.

This means: imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent - if u cant reach remote/native registry while starting up, use the image that was alraedy downloaded/pulled earlier (at the first deployment) to the local repository.

I have found that kube-system deployments manifest are set this what and probably this is why they work even though there is no internet.